# In JavaScript, why does num == [num]?

Tags: javascript, numbers

Is there a reason as to why these statements evaluate to true?

```
0 == [0];
1 == [1];
5 == [5];
5000 == [5000];
1000000 == [1000000];
```

So basically any number equals itself wrapped in an array? What's the logic behind this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because the [non-strict equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) coerces both its operands to strings in this case, and the string representation of an array is the elements it contains, delimited by commas:

```
>>> [1, 5].toString()
"1,5"
```

Since the arrays in your question only contain one element, their string representation is the same as their element's:

```
>>> [5000].toString()
"5000"
```

Answer (score 1):

`[0]` is an array with one element "0". So `0 == [0]` would be the equivalent of doing:

`0 == myArray(0)` in another language. Where `myArray(0) returns the value at the index 0`, which in this case would be 0.

That's my understanding of JavaScript arrays.  Someone else may want to jump in and correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Because == does not compare type of the variable, and === does compare type of the variable, so:

```
0 == [0]  //true
0 === [0] // false
```

In the same case:

```
0 == '0'  //true
0 === '0' //false
```

Answer (score 0):

One reason behind this is the operator used is "==" which compares only compares values and not data types as in 1=="1" is true.